# How do we get this site more popular and how to gain more active users?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that unfortunately there are not a lot of active users here (anymore). What can we (starting with myself) do to gain more popularity on this site?

To start with I've invited a few medical students to join.

Comment: I think the primary problem is not enough people **answering** questions. The majority of visitors to this site arrive via search engines, not by coming here and browsing questions. And we do enjoy a high ranking in those search engines. But all too often when you click a link from a search, you arrive at a question with no answers. How to convince more knowledgeable people to spend time writing good answers? That, I don't know.

Comment: @CareyGregory That insight is news to me. I thought we were getting too much BS and even off-topic questions (which are then even answered, against stated policy aims, and that then upvoted, even if giving advice, being mediocre, etc ). So much so, that recently people who should know better come here, hastily mis- reading non-advice answers as 'do this home remedy' advice). ––  Questions of what I consider good and on-topic are not increasing. So should we roll back the name/scope change?

Comment: @LаngLаngС I don't know what you're referring to regarding people who should know better misreading answers. Can you point me to this?

Comment: @LаngLаngС And to answer your question, hell no we shouldn't roll back the name/scope change. If that's done, you can count me done. But I really wish you'd explain your comment I asked about above. If it was a mistake I made, I'd like to go back and review it.

Comment: I think your idea of inviting medical students to join is a good idea **as long as they are happy to follow the community guidelines on prior research etc.** The more students know about the site, the more (hopefully) we will start to get questions which are on-topic and helpful. The flip-side is that the amount of the off-topic (mostly self-help) questions regularly appearing can put some off. I have sometimes come close myself in giving up and leaving SE as a whole due to the problem, not only here but in Psychology.SE

Comment: @CareyGregory - I am not sure about lack of answerers as such, but I get annoyed when there are answers giving advice to off-topic self-help questions, and some based on their own experience of the condition and not based on actual medical knowledge. This compounds the issue where we have the community guidelines where we don’t give medical advice on here and can put some off coming here again.

Comment: @ChrisRogers When you see people answering with medical advice flag it. I delete such answers but answers aren't as easy to monitor as questions so I may not notice them.

Comment: I must admit, it’s been a while now, but I will in future. Thanks @CareyGregory

Comment: My private life has been very busy, that's why I have disappeared for so long.